# Is there a substitution which transforms every Fermat curve into an elliptic curve?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, substitution

A Fermat Curve of degree $n$ is the set of solutions to $x^n+y^n=z^n$, $x,y,z\in \mathbb R$. In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346512/substitutions-that-transform-fermat-equations-to-elliptic-curves), the OP provides a substitution which relates a Fermat Curve of degree $n=3,4$ to two different elliptic curves. To transform the Fermat Curve of degree $3$, the substitutions
$$ a=\frac{12z}{x+y},\quad b=\frac{36(x-y)}{x+y} $$
produce $b^2=a^3-432$, an elliptic curve. Similarly for the Fermat Curve of degree $4$, the substitutions
$$ a=\frac{2(y^2+z^2)}{x^2},\quad b=\frac{4y(y^2+z^2)}{x^3} $$
give $b^2=a^3-4a$. However, the substitutions used are not at all obvious, which leads me to wonder,

> Is there a similar substitution which can relate a Fermat curve of arbitrary degree to an elliptic curve?

How can we even begin to prove this? I suspect the proof or disproof of this statement will be way above my level; I truly have no clue where to begin. Can someone help out? If this is somehow an open problem, then any links to literature is also appreciated!

---

**Edit:** This question has been [asked and answered on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/319084/130100). (Yay!)

Comment: In the language of algebraic geometry, you're asking whether every Fermat curve has a nonconstant morphism to an elliptic curve.