# Fermat curve in Weierstrass form.

Tags: elliptic-curves

In this post ([Substitutions that transform Fermat Equations to Elliptic Curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346512/substitutions-that-transform-fermat-equations-to-elliptic-curves)) it is proved that there exists a change of variables that trasform Fermat's curve $X^3+Y^3+Z^3=0$ into $y^2=x^3-432$, which is an elliptic curve in Weierstrass form. But this only work in characteristic $\neq 2,3$, that is becuase we have to divide by $6$ at some point.

My question is if we can do the same in the case of characteristic $2$ and $3$, because every ''standard'' change of variable I've tried needs multiplying or dividing by $2$ or $3$ at some point, which fails in our case.

Any hints or help will be appreciated.

Comment: In characteristic $3$ it is $(X+Y+Z)^3$ whose vanishing set is $\cong\Bbb{P}^1$. In characteristic 2 it should be an elliptic curve, the Weirstrass form will be $y^2+y=f(x)$ or $y^2+xy=f(x)$

Comment: @reuns thanks, the case of characteristic $3$ was easy... thanks. I know that the elliptic curves in characteristic $2$ is of one of these two ways, but I can't find the change that sends $X^3+Y^3+Z^3=0$ to this form.